Read Hyperlink Value to Presented Slide
I have a table on slide 2 of my PowerPoint presentation with three values: 100, 120, and 300. I have hyperlinked these values to slides 4, 5, and 6, respectively.
I want to write a VBA code that returns the value from slide 2 (100, 120, or 300) based on which slide I'm on during the presentation. Basically I want to find the number that lives on slide 2 that I hyperlinked to the current slide I'm on.
For example, if I'm presenting slide 4, the code should return 100, if I'm on slide 5, it should return 120, and if I'm on slide 6, it should return 300. How can I implement this in VBA?

Sorry, you haven't described the the problem you're trying to solve sufficiently. It seems you have a table containing hyperlinks to three slides. Then you click on a hyperlink and you want a variable to change its value? Please explain in more detail. If you're running a macro from the chosen slide, you could have PowerPoint check the SlideIndex or SlideID of the slide, then set the variable according to that information.

I found the answer to my question
Sub CheckSlideNumberHyperlink()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim hyperlink As hyperlink
    Dim current_slide_index As Integer
    Dim slide_index As Integer


    ' Set the slide you want to check

    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

    ' Get current slide number
    Set current_slide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.slide
    current_slide_index = current_slide.slideIndex

    ' Loop through all hyperlinks on the slide

    For Each hyperlink In slide.Hyperlinks

        ' Check if the hyperlink is associated with the slide number

        If IsSlideNumberHyperlink(hyperlink) Then

            ' Get the target slide number

            targetSlideNumber = hyperlink.SubAddress
            problem_value = hyperlink.TextToDisplay
            parts = Split(targetSlideNumber, ",")
            slide_index = parts(1)


            If current_slide_index = slide_index Then
                MsgBox problem_value
            End If
        

        End If

    Next hyperlink

End Sub


I am not sure if you maybe should stick to correct declarations.
Dim slide As slide
Dim hyperlink As hyperlink
might not work
When you write slide without the capital letter, it might not bind correctly to the Slide object type. In VBA, capitalization helps distinguish between generic variables and specific object types. If you declare Dim slide As slide, VBA might not recognize it as the specific Slide object type, which can lead to runtime errors or unexpected behavior.

Strange - the editor is autocorrecting those to lowercase. Maybe a Mac thing?

It is correcting to lower case likely so that it does not get confused with the Slide object. I would suggest you rename it to oSlide, sL or whatever name that is different from Slide
